# Self-defined tensorflow decoder TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, encoder-decoder

I am using tensorflow 2.0 for training my own attention model,
however I ran into one big issue when building my decoder class,
like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3042369c4295> in <module>
      9     enc_hidden_h=fw_sample_state_h,
     10     enc_hidden_c=fw_sample_state_c,
---> 11     enc_output=sample_output)
     12 
     13 print ('Decoder output shape: (batch_size, vocab size) {}'.format(sample_decoder_output.shape))

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

And my encoder-decoder attention model is like below
Encoder: which is a self-defined pBLSTM

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, lstm_units, final_units, batch_sz, conv_filters, mfcc_dims):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.final_units = final_units
        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.conv_filters = conv_filters
        self.mfcc_dims = mfcc_dims

        # Convolution layer to extract feature after MFCC
        self.conv_feat = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=self.conv_filters, 
                                                kernel_size=self.mfcc_dims, 
                                                padding='valid', 
                                                activation='relu', 
                                                strides=self.mfcc_dims)

    def call(self, x):
        '''
        build a pyramidal LSTM neural network encoder
        '''
        # Convolution Feature Extraction
        x = self.conv_feat(x)

        # initialize states for forward and backward
        initial_state_fw = None
        initial_state_bw = None

        counter = 0
        while(x.shape[1] > self.final_units):
            counter += 1
            # forward LSTM
            fw_output, fw_state_h, fw_state_c = self.build_lstm(True)(x, initial_state=initial_state_fw)

            # backward LSTM
            bw_output, bw_state_h, bw_state_c = self.build_lstm(False)(x, initial_state=initial_state_bw)

            x = tf.concat([fw_output, bw_output], -1)
            x = self.reshape_pyramidal(x)

            initial_state_fw = [fw_state_h, fw_state_c]
            initial_state_bw = [bw_state_h, bw_state_c]

        print(f"Encoder pyramid layer number: {counter}\n")
        return x, (fw_state_h, fw_state_c), (bw_state_h, bw_state_c)

    def build_lstm(self, back=True):
        '''
        build LSTM layer for forward and backward
        '''
        return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=self.lstm_units, 
                                    return_sequences=True, 
                                    return_state=True, 
                                    go_backwards=back)

    def reshape_pyramidal(self, outputs):
        '''
        After concatenating forward and backward outputs
        return the reshaped output
        '''
        batch_size, time_steps, num_units = outputs.shape

        return tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size, -1, num_units * 2))
```

Attention Model: which is built following this paper: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04025v5

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, query, values):
        # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
        # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
        # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
        # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
        query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

        # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
        # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
        score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
            self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

        # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

        # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
        context_vector = attention_weights * values
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights
```

Decoder: A 1-layer LSTM decoder

```
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, target_sz, embedding_dim, decoder_units, batch_sz, **kwargs):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.decoder_units = decoder_units
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_sz, embedding_dim)
        self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.decoder_units)
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=self.decoder_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_sz)


    def call(self, x, enc_hidden_h, enc_hidden_c, enc_output):
        '''
        build LSTM decoder
        '''
        # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(enc_hidden_h, enc_output)

        # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        x = self.embedding(x)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the LSTM
        output, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(x)

        # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
        output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[-1]))

        # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
        x = self.fc(output)

        return x, (state_h, state_c), attention_weights
```

I ran into that error when testing with my example input like below

```
example_input_batch, example_target_batch = next(iter(dataset))
sample_output, (fw_sample_state_h, fw_sample_state_c), bw_sample_state = encoder(example_input_batch)
decoder = Decoder(target_sz=PHONEME_SIZE, 
                  embedding_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                  decoder_units=LSTM_UNITS, 
                  batch_sz=BATCH_SIZE)

sample_target_size = tf.random.uniform((BATCH_SIZE, 1))
sample_decoder_output, sample_decoder_hidden, attention_weights = decoder(
    x=sample_target_size, 
    enc_hidden_h=fw_sample_state_h, 
    enc_hidden_c=fw_sample_state_c, 
    enc_output=sample_output)
```

Comment: You need to specify your inputs and outputs when creating a decoder... try this: `decoder = Decoder(inputs=example_input_batch, target_sz=PHONEME_SIZE, embedding_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, decoder_units=LSTM_UNITS, batch_sz=BATCH_SIZE, outpus=sample_output)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Anwarvic. I've tried your suggestion, but since I didn't define inputs in my class, so it raised ```TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'inputs')```. Due to I would like to use the decoder later in my for loop, I decided to put inputs, which is x, in ```call```

Comment: These arguments weren't for your `Decoder` class. They were for the superclass `tf.keras.Model`

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with superclass. Could you please show me the right example, please?

Comment: Let's try one more thing.. in the `call` method inside `Decoder` class change the variable name from `x` to `inputs`

Comment: Oops! there it goes by changing ```x``` into ```inputs```. Thanks a lot, @Anwarvic, Have no idea why it just worked like that anyway.

Comment: Glad I could help!! I've added the answer... it could be helpful for other people

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer @Anwarvic. That bothered me for eight hours last night. If will definitely be helpful for others.

Comment: Glad I could help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was that the poster was inheriting from `tf.keras.Model` while creating the `Decoder()` class. And this superclass was expecting an `inputs` argument in the `__call__()` operator.

So, this error can be resolved by change `x` to `inputs` in the `Decoder.call()` method like so:

```
def call(self, inputs, enc_hidden_h, enc_hidden_c, enc_output):
    '''
    build LSTM decoder
    '''
    # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(enc_hidden_h, enc_output)

    # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(inputs)

    # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

    # passing the concatenated vector to the LSTM
    output, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(x)

    # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
    output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[-1]))

    # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
    x = self.fc(output)

    return x, (state_h, state_c), attention_weights
```